# CodePipeline - Pass commit message from Source Action to Approval Action

Tags: aws-codepipeline

In AWS Codepipeline - Is there a way to pass info related to the trigger (ex: Commit Message content) from the Source Action to the "CustomData" field of the Manual Approval action ?
Note: NotificationArn points to a Topic which has a Email subscription to Approve/Reject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

In the Source action, define the namespace:

```
"name": "Source",
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "Source",
        "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Source",
          "owner": "AWS",
          "provider": "CodeCommit",
          "version": "1"
        },
        "namespace": "SourceVariables"
```

In the approval action, use the variable:

```
"name": "Approve",
"actionTypeId": {
  "category": "Approval",
  "owner": "AWS",
  "provider": "Manual",
  "version": "1"
},
"configuration": {
  "CustomData": "Manual approval required. Message from Source is #{SourceVariables.CommitMessage}."
```